# To add fixed target column to power bi matrix

Tags: powerbi

I've created a visual matrix to show latest 8weeks quantity by column vs item by row (I did calculated column to always get latest 8weeks data, the source is updating weekly).

There's a fixed target for all weeks, but if I put quantity & target to matrix value, fixed target will be repeated every week. Is there a way to keep target only on first column (with the data updating to latest 8weeks)?

[Visual matrix wo target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw98a.png)

[Visual matrix with target (but repeating)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R658u.png)

Comment: Add (concatenate)  the Fixed target value to Row Header like - January (Target: 600). This is just a work around to keep target showing once at the beginning :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion, understand it but it will be nicer if have one separate column indicate target, wonder anyway to do it

Comment: You can also add 1 row per module with value "Target" in column where it contains 44, 45... and fill the target value in the Value field. Then you can achieve your required output.